# Authentication routing problems with angular-material-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, authentication, routes, yeoman, angular-material

Having scaffolded an angular-material-fullstack project using the yeoman generator, I have run into a problem with its verification straightaway.

It seems that there's a bug from the outset, because when clicking Signup below, the app does not redirect to the signup page as it should, rather it stays on the log in page:

[image]

Even when explicitly typed in to the address bar (localhost:9000/signup), I still get relocated to /login.

I can get to the 'main' section of the app without logging in, however, the app gets confused by this, and doesn't know what to display for the menu buttons in the main menu (should be login and sign out):

[image]

Previously in this environment the app was working like a dream. This time I opted for uiRouter rather than ngRoute, and I'm wondering if, for some reason, this may be the cause of the problem. Any help warmly appreciated.